# Apollo useQuery running only once and skipping when components re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and nextJS. In my current project, I want to fetch data only once from graphql server and use the same data all the time when components re-renders. I tried to use skip with useQuery hook but even the root component is rerendered so could not do it. I tried useLazyLoad and still no luck. Any leads would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. You could use a state for this. Load the data into the state. Because the data in the state does not change the method that retrieves the data wil not be called.

Comment: I am sorry I  did not get it. `const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(query, { variables: ...})` This is how i fetch the data and it's passed down to the child Component like `<Component data={data} />` . So, how would i run this query only once irrespective of change in value in the variables passed to the useQuery. Additionally, want to use same data object while re-rendering.